# Для чего и как применять директивы в AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

В данный момент изучаю Angular и честно говоря плохо понимаю для чего нужны директивы и где их применять. Вмоём текущем понимании это всего лишь кусок кода и шаблон, но тогда почему не пользоваться например ng-inject и работать в нём при помощи контроллера. Вобщем, подскажите пожалуйста, умудрённые опытом люди, где и как и в каком виде правильно и разумно применять директивы? Будет вдвойне полезней если ещё и ссылки на примеры накидаете.

Answer (score 1):

Как пишет автор этих статей [Директивы в Angularjs для начинающих](http://habrahabr.ru/post/179755/)
"На мой взгляд, директивы являются основной изюминкой декларативного стиля Angularjs."

Директивы позволяют делать код более наглядным и читаемым. Директивы могут очень гибко настраиваться и имеют ряд функциональных особенностей - настраивать работу scope внутри директивы, запускать свой код на разных стадиях работы директивы (compile - pre и post, link).

Answer (score 0):

Если кратко, то:

1. Повторяющиеся переиспользуемые куски разметки и логики - типа контрола.
2. Всё, где требуется работа с DOM.